# Bash script to transfer folder recursively without overwriting via FTP

Tags: bash, copy

I would need a bash script to transfer folders recursively via FTP. 
Username/password/IP - static defined.

1. Server where the script runs on: Linux
2. Source server: Samba (Linux...)
3. Dest. Server: Linux

As the files to be transferred are big database files (.bak, etc) **overwriting** should be **avoided**.
Preferably no prompting because the script has to be 'cronned', to run at night.

(I'm not a hero in bash, but I have the impression it's the easiest for this situation)

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If the destination server is Linux might I suggest just using rsync with an ssh key?  FTP is unencrypted and doesn't have native support for incremental backups.

A single rsync with a command line such as the below could suffice.

```
rsync -auv -e "ssh -i /path/to/keyfile" /path/to/source_directory/* \
    user@remotehost:/path/to/destination_directory/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mount [FTPfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) and `cp` everything there. Make sure you disable delta-transfer so it doesn't download files from there :)

BTW, how are you going to make these backups without overwriting? you'll have a bunch of old files mixed with some new ones if you don't use `date` in folder name.

Comment: Possibly by comparing the file names first? But how I'll do that practically...

Comment: Install FTPfs, and mount FTPfs somewhere (for instance, /mnt/backup: `curlftpfs ftp://ftp.sunet.se/ /mnt/backup`). Then set this to cron: `cp -R -n /i/wanna/backup/this /mnt/backup/ > /dev/null`